# How to configure the Thread Pool for a HTTP Server in Micronaut

Tags: java, netty, micronaut

I'm trying to configure a HTTP Server for an API made in Micronaut 3.7.5. Reviewing the Micronaut [documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#serverConfiguration) I found many ways to do it and I not sure which is the best way.

1. **Worker event-loop:**. If I set a event-loop name not used

```
micronaut.server.netty.worker.event-loop-group
micronaut.server.netty.worker.threads
```

2. **Default event-loop:** This event-loop is shared with clients also, unless I specify a diferent event-loop for them

```
micronaut.netty.event-loops.default.num-threads
```

3. **Parent event-loop:** I cound't find any documentation about it and how to use it

```
micronaut.server.netty.parent.event-loop-group
micronaut.server.netty.parent.threads
```

Comment: How the event-loop is shared with clients in your case? I don't know any framework that would easily share the event-loop, the state of course, but with state is that the client modifies the state and sends it back to the server which reads it with its normal event-loop.
No parent loop? Who's the child? Client? nah. Event-loop-group's' are something different. Event-loop groups are the threads assigned to that loop.
I might be wrong, but if so, please clarify a little bit more in the question or comment, thanks.

Comment: I love how there's zero documentation for the parent event-loop or how it differentiates from the worker thread group. Let's say the worker thread group is being slow. Is that bottle necking the server which could lead to dropped requests? Or does that only happen if you block the parent event loop threads. Where are the architecture diagrams? Why am I using Micronaut again :(